# Trying to get a multilevel category tree using pdo and get PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function build_category_tree() in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am very new to OOP and haven't been programing in php in years, but essentially what I am trying to do is to display a multilevel category tree in a CRUD application. I have a Category class and a method that will be the one to display the appropriate category based on the parent_id. As of now my other attempts display the whole thing, that as is all categories and subcategories in a select statement. this is my Category class you'll notice I tried a few things, that didn't work.

```
class Category{

// database connection and table name
private $conn;
private $table_name = "menu";

// object properties
public $id;
public $name;
public $parent_id;

public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn = $db;
}
//Builds the category tree recursively fetching data    
function build_category_tree(&$output, $preselected, $parent=0, $indent=""){
 $query = "SELECT id, name FROM menu WHERE parent_id = " . $parent . "
";

while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$selected = ($r["id"] == $preselected) ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "";
$output .= "<option value=\"" . $r["id"] . "\" " . $selected . ">" . $indent . $r["name"] . "</option>";
if($r["id"] != $parent){
  build_category_tree($output, $preselected, $r["id"], $indent . "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
}
}

}
// used by select drop-down list
function read(){
    //select all data
   $query  = "SELECT
                id, name
            FROM
                " . $this->table_name . "";  
/*$query = "SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4, t5.name as lev5\n"
. "FROM menu AS t1\n"
. "LEFT JOIN menu AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id\n"
. "LEFT JOIN menu AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.id\n"
. "LEFT JOIN menu AS t4 ON t4.parent_id= t3.id\n"
. "LEFT JOIN menu AS t5 ON t5.parent_id= t4.id\n"
. "WHERE t1.parent_id = 0";*/
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}
function readName(){
 /*$query = "SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4, t5.name as lev5\n"
. "FROM menu AS t1\n"
. "LEFT JOIN menu AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id\n"
. "LEFT JOIN menu AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.id\n"
. "LEFT JOIN menu AS t4 ON t4.parent_id= t3.id\n"
. "LEFT JOIN menu AS t5 ON t5.parent_id= t4.id\n"
. "WHERE t1.parent_id = ? limit 0,1";*/
$query = "SELECT name FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE id = ? ";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$this->name = $row['name'];

 }



}
```

The next script builds the select tag with the appropriate categories. As I have 5 levels of categories I am trying to simplify the SELECT and make it more manageable.

```
     // read the product categories from the database
     include_once 'objects/category.php';

$category = new Category($db);
$stmt = $category->read();



/* //This works fine in a single level that is no subcategories
echo "<select class='form-control' name='category_id'>";
      echo "<option>Seleccioná la categoría...</option>";

    while ($row_category = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row_category);
        echo "<option value='{$id}'>{$name}</option>";
    }*/
// put them in a select drop-down
$category->build_category_tree($locations, 0);  

// echo "</select>";
?><select><?php echo $locations ?></select>
<!-- Test other options -->
<select>
<option value="-1">Seleccioná la categoría</option> 
<?php echo $locations ?>
```

Comment: that's not a function, it's a method, so when you are making the recursive call you still need to apply it to an object, I am guessing that the current one, so `$this->build_category_tree(...)`

Comment: What do you mean? I applied it inside the class as 
`if($r["id"] != $parent){
  $this->build_category_tree($output, $preselected, $r["id"], $indent . "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
}` it didn't work still same error ... should be called elsewhere?

Comment: The error message should tell you where the problem. The part you added in the title ends with "Call to undefined function build_category_tree() in" but right after that the message shows you the file name and the line number. If you go in that file, at that specific line you will see that you are calling `build_category_tree` as a function, not a method

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/n/objects/category.php on line 21

line 21 is the class method
$category->build_category_tree($locations, 0);